# Explode by spaces from excel string

Tags: php

I try to explode by space from string from excel

```
<?php

$string = 'RT 2';

print_r(explode(' ', $string));

// I try
$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $string);
// and this
preg_match("/([а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)/iu", $string, $parts);
```

But it does not works. This is not spase. It is something else.

**Example** - https://ideone.com/S7SEEE

If bin2hex()

```
$string = 'RT 2';
var_dump(bin2hex($string));
// string(10) "5254c2a032"
```

Comment: `urlencode` is a quick way to check what byte values are in a string where “special” characters might be hiding.

Comment: Example - https://ideone.com/S7SEEE

Comment: @Teretto You have a non-breaking space in there. This is not the same as a normal space character, which you're attempt to split by.

Comment: @Jeto ok, how can I remove all spaces and non-breaking spaces and something else to explode string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Edit:** see Karol Samborski's answer instead, adding the `u` flag
>   changes the scope of `/s` to include all unicode spaces.

You can use the Unicode sequence of a non-breaking space, which would be `\x00A0` (in regex format), and add the corresponding `/u` (Unicode) flag to your regex:

```
$string = 'RT 2';

print_r(preg_split('/[\s\x00A0]+/u', $string));
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/d7pld**

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest solution that works is:

```
<?php

$string = 'RT 2';

print_r(preg_split('/\s+/u', $string));
```

You don't need to specify concrete unicode characters representing space. The `/u` flag adds it whole spectrum of spaces to the `\s` character class.

Comment: You're right, didn't realize the `/u` flag was changing the scope of `\s` itself. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Your string has a *special* blankspace in it, you can always investigate bytes using `dechex(ord());` or `bin2hex()` or `unpack()`.

```
52 54 c2 a0 32 
^... R      ^... 2
         ^... non-breaking space
   ^... T (2 bytes)
```

This regex covers normal space characters, non-breaking space and narrow space character:

```
/[\x202F\x00A0\s]/
```

Use `\u` for regex and `\x` for preg matches (PCRE compatible).